# align environment inside enumerate?

Tags: align, enumerate

Is there a good way to use the align* environment inside enumerate? So far, it's perfect except for the extra spacing at the start of a bullet. I've seen recommendations to use aligned but it seems aligned does not support \intertext, which I sort of need. Adding negative vertical space is my current solution, but it doesn't seem like a great one.

```
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
  \item Since the order in which the team members are picked does not matter:
        \[\dbinom{12}{3} = \boxed{220}\]
  \item There are $\binom{7}{2}$ ways of selecing the women and $\binom{5}{1}$
        ways of selecting the men. There are 220 total ways (from part (a)):
        \[\dfrac{\binom{7}{2} \binom{5}{1}}{220} = \boxed{\dfrac{21}{44}}\]
  \item \begin{align*}
            \intertext{Let $W$ be the event that there are at least two women on the team, and let
                $M$ be the event that there is at least one man on the team. There are}
            \dbinom{7}{2}\dbinom{5}{1} + \dbinom{7}{3}\dbinom{5}{0} & = 140                   \\
            \intertext{teams with at least two women. There are}
            \dbinom{7}{2}\dbinom{5}{1}                              & = 105                   \\
            \intertext{teams with at least two women and at least one man
                (the same as exactly two women and one man!). Therefore,}
            P(M|W) = \dfrac{105}{140}                               & = \boxed{\dfrac{3}{4}}.
        \end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
```

The above looks something like this:
[image]

Comment: why is the Let W text not before the align, rather than inside it with intertext?

Comment: Whoops, that's such a simple solution I missed. Thank you!